# Setup a Gmail filter to be applied to messages that do not contain a given text

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I really need to setup filter in Gmail but it is not working. Where and how I have to enter the words which will be in the message I want to receive, and if the message do not contain those words to be deleted or archived. So far I was doing this:

Example:
In the field 'Doesn't have' I enter the words which should be in the message I want to receive like ( football -germany OR basketball -NBA OR handball -austria etc.). And for example if the message contain "football -spain"-(not mentioned in Doesn't have)  should be archived in this case right?

I don't understand the rules I have to use, what do I have to enter in 'has the words' and 'doesn't have'? What I have now does not work.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to describe one kind of message you're trying to filter on? Don't do it in terms of the filter; just describe it in normal terms. Like: "I'm trying to filter on messages that contain the word 'football' but do not contain the word 'germany'."

Comment: Note that Gmail filters work best with positive matches: "Do something if a message matches these things". It's harder to do negative matches: "Do something _unless_ a message matches these things".

Answer (score 9):

As said in the comments, Gmail filters work best when you tell it what to look for, not what not to look for. This being said, if you would like to filter out all mail besides mail containing "football" *and* "germany" *or* "basketball" *and* "NBA", you should enter `(football germany) OR (basketball NBA)` in the "Doesn't have" field. (See attached screenshot for example)

[image: gmailFilterExample.jpg]

Source: [Gmail Help: Advanced Search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Comment: In the latest version, google move everything to "Has the words" section: So you have to put: from:(interesting@example.com) -{(nointeresting@example.com)} subject:(something) -{(avoid)} and so on

Comment: @TitoLeiva I'm not sure what you mean by your comment *`"Google move everything to  "Has the words"`*.  See this [screenshot from Gmail 
 taken a few moments ago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHqOU.png)

Comment: @BlindSpots I tried to use the "Doesn't have" but the only thing that it works was a complex query in the "Has the words" like this:

from:(azuredevops@microsoft.com) -{(mentioned you)} subject:-{(Cristóbal Leiva)}

Comment: @TitoLeiva If you want to open a question asking how to use the "Doesn't have" section instead of the "Has the words" section with your search I'd be happy to explain further.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify where the 'doesn't have' is to look.

Instead of:
`(football germany)`
enter:
`Subject: (football germany)`
or
`Body: (football germany)`

Comment: this solved my problem, you can also club multiple with AND and OR

Answer (score 2):

Since Gmail works best when telling it what to look for you can try the following.

1. create a a series of filters:

   - one finding German football and adding an appropriate label, and archiving it
   - one finding austrian handball and adding an appropriate label, and archiving it
   - one finding ome and adding an appropriate label, and archiving it

Note: more than one filter can add the same label; and more than one filter could apply.

2. enable multiple inboxes via labs.
3. set the configuration for multiple inboxes to put the "Extra panels positioning: above the inbox"
4. for up to 5 extra inboxes you can define a rule for what will show in the inbox. It can be as simple as "label:x" or more complex such as "label:germanfootball or label:NBA"

Now all the conversations you care about will be in the extra inboxes at the top, and everything else will be in the normal inbox at the bottom.

note: using priority inbox can mess up this arrangement, so I just use the default inbox under settings/inbox.

Example:
In the field 'Doesn't have' I enter the words which should be in the message I want to receive like ( football -germany OR basketball -NBA OR handball -austria etc.). And for example if the message contain "football -spain"-(not mentioned in Doesn't have) should be archived in this case right?